# Two floating columns in container, best way to increase container height to match columns?

Tags: css, html

I've searched at the Stack Overflow and other sources, for example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ep57zbug/7/).

This is the code, I'm talking about:

```
.container{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%; /*adjust this manually and no issue*/
        background: #222222;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
}
```

There is a jsfiddle of the section I'm talking about. If the container is changed to (say) 180%  it solves all because it's made bigger than everything so everything is sitting on top of it.

I have a container which is the parent here and a child called content which has 2 columns in it. When I write too much in the column, it goes over the container as they are both floating. I can change it manually, so once I'm happy with the text just change the height which is OK. But, I don't think this is good practice and I'm sure there is another way that does it automatically by canceling all the floats. I cant get it to work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust your CSS like this:

```
/*
Dark Grey: #222222 
Orange: #ff8a00
Light Orange: #ffcc8f
White: #ffffff

*/
body {
    background: url("images/river.jpg") no-repeat top center fixed;
    background-color: #222222;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
h2 {
    color:#ff8a00;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    letter-spacing: 8px;
    padding:30px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ff8a00;
    width:50%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-top:5%;
}
h3 {
    color:#ff8a00;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    letter-spacing: 8px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ff8a00;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-top:5%;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: #222222;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position:relative;
}
.content {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 60%;
    height: auto;
    text-align:center;
    background: #fc0;
    /*Change to #222222 */
    font-family: proximaNova;
    font-size:1.1em;
    color:white;
    display:block;
}
.bio {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    text-align:center;
    background: #222222;
    /*Change to #222222 */
    font-family: proximaNova;
    font-size:1em;
    font-style:normal;
    margin-top:30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.left-column {
    width: 48%;
    display:inline-block;
    height: auto;
    text-align:left;
    background: black;
    /*Change to #222222 */
    font-family: proximaNova;
    font-size:1.0em;
    margin-top:5%;
}
.right-column {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 48%;
    height: auto;
    text-align:left;
    background: black;
    /*Change to #222222 */
    font-family: proximaNova;
    font-size:1.0em;
    margin-top:5%;
}
.footer {
    width:100%;
    background-color: white;
    text-align:center;
    color:#222222;
    font-size:1em;
    font-family: proximaNova;
}
.nav-text {
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:25px;
    font-family:trench;
    font-size:22px;
    color: white;
    float:left;
}
```

You're adding 100% height everywhere, as if that's the solution to everything, and that's the cause to most of your issues. If you want to auto adjust sizes to anything then the logical answer for the property is... *auto*. By setting all your 100% heights to auto and getting rid of your floats (you could use floats, but you must clear them, as we're at it, so showing you another option), you can do this easily, without the ultra complicated and convoluted ways you were trying.

I've [**forked your fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2vt6f3u2/) so you can add paddings, margins etc. Also changed the background on one of your divs just so you see how the box model works, but of course you can (and should) change it to anything

See MDN page for more info on [**HEIGHT PROPERTY**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) syntax, behavior and examples

Comment: Fantastic. Yes i was making heights to 100% because im making it mobile compatable, and i was having a few issues with auto. Ill test this out! Appreciate it!

Comment: in these cases you add 100% to the outer container so it contains everything. If you need 100% for an element, of course you can add 100%, but keep in mind that will be the behavior: 100%. If you want auto, then just add auto. And remember you can control layout elements with min-height and max-height. Same conditions apply for width. Also, if you're interested in mobile development and heights, I'd recommend you take a look to viewport sizes, because they'll make your life easier

Comment: Oh i will be sure to check out view port sizes. Ive used it on my site a little. I prefer your method to solving this over others. However, the gap between the columns is very small, and i cant float the images to the sides now. Any ideas? Cheers, i just wanted a bigger gap between them without increasing the size of the columns themselves.

Comment: sure. as a matter of fact you don't need "right-column" and "left-column", remember to use re-usable classes as much as possible, so you can simply take the style from one of the columns, name it `.col` and then use that class for both columns. And for the gap, you can use both margins or paddings, that's why I said "I've forked your fiddle so you can add paddings, margins etc" and added a different color box so you can easily see how it reacts. Play around and see, but basically remember: your padding+margin+width+border has to be 50% or less

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/harutyunabgaryan/ep57zbug/9/)

```
.container{
        width: 100%;

        background: #222222;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Ive already tried this. No luck im afraid. It wouldnt make a difference to the container.

Comment: Remove height:100% and set float:left ;

Comment: Thanks Harut, i think i tried this before. So if i want to add text under the two columns i just need to create another container like i have been doing. Great thanks. Ill mark as a good answer once ive tested on mobile.

Comment: Yes you need add another conteiner

Comment: Magic, just testing now.. Im trying to figure out why exactly this worked? I dont see how a float with 2 floats in it solves the height issue? Or was the issue with the height just being set?

Comment: if you set main div float left and inside set div float left parent div get height in child divs height